# How to use another brackets/tabs policy for my CSS?

Tags: css, sublimetext, sublimetext2

Here is an example of what is happening now:

```
.class {

}
```

So when I'm typing `.class {` **SublimeText** automatically inserts `}` (which is correct).
Then I press *Enter* and get this:

```
.class {
    #CURSOR_POSITION#
}
```

But what I really want is (attention to the closing bracket):

```
.class {
    #CURSOR_POSITION#
    }
```

I've even seen (ok, it was only once) in some editor special setting for this. Now I start using SublimeText (which is cool!) and I feel that it can be customized in a such way but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok! It's not really hard to do it but it was not simple to know how to do it =)

So my approach is:

1. Write a simple macro (I've edited the default `Enter` macro called `Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro` which lives in `~Data/Packages/Default`) and save it with a new name.
   I've called it `CSS.Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro` and put in `~Data/Packages/User`.

   ```
   [
       {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n\n"} },
       {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardbol", "extend": false} },
       {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t"} },
       {"command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false} },
       {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol", "extend": false} },
       {"command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": true} }
   ]
   ```
2. Apply it for `Enter` key in CSS files. For that we need to fo to Preferences > Key Bindings - User (it will open `~Data/Packages/User/Default (YOUR_OPERATING_SYSTEM).sublime-keymap`) and paste there the following code:

   ```
   [
       { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/CSS.Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
           [
               { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css" },
               { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
               { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
               { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
               { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
           ]
       }
   ]
   ```

   It is copy-pasted from the defult keybinding file with one context addition:
   `{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css" }`
   which tells Sublime to apply it only for CSS ext.
3. Profit!

Comment: Thank you for this, it has been driving me crazy for some time now.

Comment: Glad to see that it's needed by someone else :)